# get all tables names that start with a string

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I've lot of tables in my database and I wanted to know if there is any way I can get all the tables names that start with a certain string.

For example, I have this string: `my_table` and I would like to get all of the tables names that starts with it. The expected result would be `my_table_*` so it's pretty much everything that starts with it.

Is it possible?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: SHOW TABLES LIKE 'my_table_*'; ?

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.mysql-list-tables.php

Comment: You seriously could have googled that and found the answer in like 5 seconds, next time search around a bit before just coming over here and asking questions

Comment: @LemuelBotha Wasn't sure what to look for.. Appreciate your attitude.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple command:

SHOW TABLES LIKE 'my_table*'

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT table_name 
  FROM information_schema.tables 
 WHERE table_name LIKE 'string_here%';
```

Should do the trick

Comment: This will retrieve from all databases.

Comment: This would be more precise I think:  SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_name like '%string_here%'AND TABLE_SCHEMA = 'thedbyouwant';

Comment: Thanks :)! however, the guy below you gave a shorter answer which does the job as-well.